# How to draw charts(Graphs) in Oracle Form (11g & above)

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, oracleforms

i want to draw charts(pie and
bar charts ) in oracle form
builder using bean component in oracle form block.

```
SET_CUSTOM_PROPERTY()
```

using bean property as mentioned above. If anyone refers to or share links/ document where i can found all the properties related to graphs are just like

```
SET_CUSTOM_PROPERTY('control1.b_g',1,'ADD_ROWDATA','Gender'||VD||J.EMP||VD||j.GEN);
SET_CUSTOM_PROPERTY('control1.b_g',1,'ADD_DATA_TO_GRAPH','AREA_VERT_ABS');
```

I needed all the properties for setting the charts lable,name,tooltips,color,etc.
if some have .pdf or oracle .doc like reffer it here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to contact the vendor (or developer if within your own company) that created the bean.

Comment: I am talking about general properties of setting graps.like how to tooltip,,how to set title and etc

Comment: All the properties of your own bean are coded in the bean, which you either wrote, purchased, found on the Internet, or got as a very old Demo from Oracle.  If you are using the old Oracle Demos, they included documentation that tells you how to use the demo and all the properties and how to set them.  In the old demo set, the charting was referred to as BIBEANS because it used/required a BiBeans JAR file in order to be used.  Refer to the discussion here:   https://forums.oracle.com/ords/apexds/post/charts-graphs-in-oracle-form-12c-11g-6139